# AX 2012 Workflow All Information in a form

Tags: workflow, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, data-dictionary

I am working on Ax2012 workflow. I need to know about the table in data dictionary where all the information of configuration of the workflow stores. I know I have to trace many tables to get all the information i.e users , Final Approver , Comments , Description, User whom which workflow are assigned , Workflow Steps , Sequences of the workflowItems etc. I need to know tables from which I can get this Information. 
I need all the information of the workflow.

- Workflow Assigned to the users.
- Comments when workflow Submitted
- Comments when some accept the workflow
- Workflow Descriptions
- Workflow last Approval
- User Who submit the workflow
- All the paths in the workflow of the configuration

like

- 1st path(Start---->condition------>True Condition approval)
- 2nd path(Start---->condition------>false condition approval)

Thanks For helping me out.

Comment: Did you try cross references? Or can you tell us more about why you need this list of tables? Currently your question is a bit broad for the scope of Stack Overflow, try to make it more specific.

Comment: I think thats enough information now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Tutorial of getting all possible paths of workflow configuration

https://github.com/SohaibAnwaar/Ax-2012-Tutorials/tree/master/AX/july/18%20July

[image: Saving all the paths to excel file]

Tutorial of getting all the information related to the workflow in the form

https://github.com/SohaibAnwaar/Ax-2012-Tutorials/tree/master/AX/july/13%20july

[image: Workflow Description]

Details of the Workflow

[image]

Comment: Could you [edit] a summary of the linked solution into the answer? If the links are not available in the future, the answer would be still useful then.